# after upgrading R, can I automatically update the packages

Tags: r, package

I know how to reinstall all packages by hand, but is there a one-command way to do this? The following shows that update.packages() does not do the trick.

```
> library(xtable)
Error in library(xtable) : there is no package called ‘xtable’
> update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)
> library(xtable)
Error in library(xtable) : there is no package called ‘xtable’
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0   
> update.packages()
> library(xtable)
Error in library(xtable) : there is no package called ‘xtable’
>
```